# Slickgrid grouping, how to handle large amounts of data?

Tags: slickgrid

I would like to use Slickgrid to handle very large amounts of data. It is not hard to implement in Slickgrid, you just need to create a custom provider, that serves the data at request.

My problem is, that I need Slickgird DataView's grouping behaviour. DataView is a provider implementation itself, so if I use that, I can not use my custom provider, and DataView (as I see) needs all the data at instantiation time.

Do you have any suggestions to use DataView's grouping feature, without needing to serve it all the data at instantiation time?

(Or do you think it's not possible easily, and I have to reimplement DataView?)

Comment: Were you able to get that working? I need the same - grouped dynamic loading. I think one of the way to do that would be to separate group hierarchy from the items, and load the group hierarchy separately. Then provide group hierarchy as requested by the grid, and dynamically load the data for current view (knowing the group we can apply corresponding filters.

Comment: Any luck. A couple years after your question and I am now looking for a solution. Can't seem to find one so I am starting here before asking a new question. Any ideas?